# How to handle request to contact poster off-site?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

While reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486630/212218 I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607067/212218):

> We are a specialized company in POS Development and we ran into your post requesting development services for the Creon terminal.
>
> We have developed several applications (financial, pre-paid, security and others) in that device. Our applications have been certified by Visa/MC members and pre-aid known distributors (MoreMagic).
>
> If you're interested in our services, please you can contact me at <email address> to review details.

It's a sales pitch followed by a CTA to contact the poster off-site.  But it is still relevant to the (admittedly *very* vague) question, so I'm hesitant to flag it as spam.

As a rule, I edit or flag any post that contains an email address or any other form of PII.  But in this case, if I were to remove the email address from the answer, there would be basically no content left in it whatsoever.

So it "smells" like it should be flagged, but I'm not sure what reason to give.

What is SO policy on posting "answers" that request that the question-asker contact the poster off-site?

Comment: Good question. Given that's their only "answer", and all it amounts to is a sales pitch, I'd think it was spam, but given the question, too... I guess the question is probably a candidate for being roasted, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not going to help anyone again ever.  It's now an ex-question.  (Closed as "too localized" if you want a flag reason for future reference.  The answer soliciting off-site contact can be flagged as spam, or "other" and explain the reason.)

Comment: ...and now it's deleted.